# Delphi collection of objects

Tags: delphi

I have created an easy class called `TIstruzione`; I need to create 4 objects at runtime and store them in an array so that I can access them when I want.

```
FList: TObjectList<TIstruzione>;
```

I have created this in the public section of TForm1 because I have seen in Delphi's documentation that this is an apposite generic container for classes. Then I am going to manage his lifetime in this way:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 FList.Create;
 FList.OwnsObjects := true;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
 FList.Destroy;
end;
```

The `OwnsObject` ensures that the objects are owned by the list and when I free the list, the objects inside are freed as well. Am I correct?

If you look at the code here, I am trying to populate the list:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var a: TIstruzione;
begin

 a := TIstruzione.Create;
 try
  a.tipo := Add;
  a.rdest := 2;
  a.dato1 := 7;
  a.dato2 := 5;
  FList.Add(a);
 finally
  a.Free;
 end;

  a := TIstruzione.Create;
 try
  a.tipo := Load;
  a.rdest := 1;
  a.dato1 := 2;
  a.dato2 := -1;
  FList.Add(a);
 finally
  a.Free;
 end;

end;
```

I have an error when the program starts. It is an access violation; any idea? Just to be complete, the class is simply this:

```
type

 TTipo = (RISC_Add, RISC_AddI, RISC_Sub, RISC_SubI, RISC_Load, RISC_Store);
 TPip = (MIPS_pipeline, PPC_pipeline);

type
 TIstruzione = class
  public
   tipo: TTipo;
   rdest: integer;
   dato1: integer;
   dato2: integer;
 end;
```

Comment: I don't think you should be freeing `a` in `TForm1.Button1Click`

Comment: why not? The value is stored in the FList before freeing it

Comment: You don't want to free it because it is owned by FLIst and will be destroyed when you free FList.

Comment: Ah ok so I don't need the try finally correct?

Comment: yes indeed, create the object and add it to the list, when the list is freed, all objects are destroyed automatically. Also note that OwnsObjects is true by default, no need to specify this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make that:

```
FList := TObjectList<TIstruzione>.Create;
```

You should never call `Create` on a variable, always use the proper constructor syntax, like above.

Also, don't `Free` the item you just added to the list:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var 
  a: TIstruzione;
begin
  a := TIstruzione.Create;
  a.tipo := Add;
  a.rdest := 2;
  a.dato1 := 7;
  a.dato2 := 5;
  FList.Add(a);

  a := TIstruzione.Create;
  a.tipo := Load;
  a.rdest := 1;
  a.dato1 := 2;
  a.dato2 := -1;
  FList.Add(a);
end;
```

The `TObjectList` is now the owner, so the objects will be freed by the `TObjectList`, and should not be freed not by you anymore. That is what `OwnsObjects := True;` means.

Comment: No wait, it's a TObjectList<TIstruzione>

Comment: Also the program crashes in the TButton1 click

Comment: Ok thanks Rudy. Just a thing: you are calling the TIstruzione.Create two times! I mean, isn't a already created?

Comment: Don't I have to create 2 different variables?

Comment: You should **not** create a `TIstruzione`, add it to the list and then `Free` it again. See my edited answer.

Comment: No need to create two different variables. The variable is just a reference, and it can be re-used once you added the item to the list.

Comment: Yeah I got it, you've just saved raffaele's day

Comment: FWIW, thanks to @whosrdaddy for editing the `TList` to `TObjectList`.